# Two tone LED night lamp

Tags: led

I am  trying to make a night lamp.  I especially like the quality and temperature of the light from a Nexus 5x flash switched on and aimed at the ceiling.  It gives out a uniform and cool light through out the room.

The flash on the phone is described as Broad-spectrum CRI-90 dual flash.

How do I build a light like that?

Comment: like what? diffused , CRI? CCT?

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to promo this product. Voting to close.

Comment: CRI90 LED's use oxynitride phosphors  whose emission ranges from 575 to 675 nm to improve Red spectral emissions vs std phosphors in the 80~82 CRI. However you still need to define warm or cool in CCT terms like 4000, 4500, 5000'K or ANSI white or some other comparison.  These can be SMD or remote phosphors inside tube.  CRI was adopted by the FL industry and they are relucant to change basedon pastel colour matching as they perform better than LEDs here.

Comment: Whereas NIST promoted the CQS standard which is based on saturated colours and LEds with RGB or RGYB or WY mixes can achieve much better than FL tubes.    The CQS did not get widespread use due to politics.  http://lumenistics.com/is-color-quality-scale-cqs-an-improvement-on-cri/  I also have Wendy's spreadsheet analyzing many light sources with CQS and CRI. Wendy is no longer at NIST and returned to teaching in NZ or AU. I think.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I would like a CRI more than 8o and CCT nearer the cooler end.

Comment: @Andy aka: I meant to reply earlier but was held up with other stuff. But I am reply surprised that this question is considered as a promo.
Nexus 5x is an android smartphone made by Google and which is no more in production.
I was merely pointing out the fact that I liked to replicate the lighting effect of it's camera flash LED.

Answer (score 2):

["CRI-90" Is a bullshit marketing term used to sell stuff.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_CRI_LED_lighting) If you want to "build a lamp like that", buy one. If you want a lamp with simular color you can probalby replicate it with an RGB LED, but setting the brightness of each LED to aproximate the [blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) of the lamp you want, if you want to do it well, you would need to get a somewhat accurate spectrometer and fiddle the brightnesses. All of this is a lot of effort when you can just buy one, so if you are going to do it understand you are going to spend a lot of time and money replicating someone elses work.

Comment: I'd remove the product link because it encourages people to click on it and this is clearly something that the spammer ahem questioner is trying to do but they didn't have the wit to embed a link. Upvote for telling it as it is.

Comment: @Andyaka good point, I found the wikipedia page and replaced the link.

Comment: Some may use CRI-90 as BS whereas others have legitimate reasons with advanced phosphors to improve colour matching of pastel colours. So I disagree with the statement as a generalization.

Comment: Since a nightlight spreading light on the ceiling is viewed as the product of emissions and reflection of paint there is more chance of spectral error from omissions vs incident light.  If you don't understand do  color test with  a white balanced LCD monitor with LED backlight and look for colour shade differences compared to diffused sunlight at mid-day as I have.

Comment: http://www.ladiesgadgets.com/integral-led-sensor-night-light/